# Better word for contributing content

Tags: website-design, navigation, user-expectation, terminology, wording

I'm working on website that heavily features user-contributed content.

I currently have a link titled "Contribute" that leads to a page explaining how a user can help, in the form of **adding** new content, **editing** existing content, or just **reporting bugs** and making **feature requests** for the site as a whole.

However, I've gotten feedback that the link reads more like a donation request than a "how to help" link.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuc3b0.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

My thoughts:

- "Contribute"
- "Help out"
- "How to Help"
- "Improve [Site Name]"

None of these stand out as clear winners.

What is a better way to word this link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### Try separating the creation / editing of content from the advice / reporting.

In your question, you're asking for 4 separate things, which fall across two categories:

- Writing and/or editing actual content
- Reporting bugs (things that are not functioning in the current site) and suggesting improvements for future upgrades of the website.

**Asking someone to write or edit** is more of a committment (and maybe an honor), so you can have a separate page just for that. You're asking people to give their time and energy in the creation of content. They also will have their name and material on the site as a result.

**Asking for suggestions or bug reporting** is being helpful in a simpler way. Other users may not see what they've asked for, but anyone should be able to easily report a bug at the least.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjHQJM.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>